# How to delete a whole substring on backspace key press in angular 8/ javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a requirement in which I want to delete the whole substring when I press back space.

Issue 1 -

Eg. If I have following text in my input -
`@User A is saying hi to @User B`

Now if I do a backspace, the whole `@User A` or `@User B` should be deleted on backspace key press.

Issue 2 -

I have a **list of users** (Eg. `@User A, @User B, @User C`... etc) which are substrings that should be deleted on single back space press.
So how to determine that on backspace press it is a substring which is present in my **list of users**.

Please suggest how can I do this in javascript / angular approach

Comment: Can you add more details, did you tried something, you defined `@user A, @user B`, how does the actual data look like, eg. does it looks like `@John paul` or `John paul`, does every user have a last name. Can you provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kx3uds

Following is the algorithm:

1. Add `KeyDown` event handler. Check if keycode is `Backspace`
2. Find the position of `@` from cursor in backward direction
3. Once found, find the substring between position at step #2 and cursor
4. Check if this string is present in a predefined array of users
5. If yes, then preventDefault operation and update the model to remove the found username.

Please use above code just as a reference. There may be some edge cases, bugs in this code. Please test it thoroughly before using in production.